# Horizontal two-row nav menu

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Here's my dilemma. I've got a total of 8 links (one being a button) on a navigation menu that I need to have in two rows all to the right. But I can't seem to get it to line up properly and still also be justified to the right. Basically the first 4 need to be on top of the other 4. It's built with bootstrap.

Main code is below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <!-- Container wrapper -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
    <!-- Toggle button -->
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarRightAlignExample"
      aria-controls="navbarRightAlignExample"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarRightAlignExample">
      <!-- Left links -->

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">CELEBRATE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">BUILD</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">SCHOLARSHIPS</a>
        </li>
        <a id="donate-btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">DONATE</a>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">YOUTH</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PLAY</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ASSIST</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">WHO MAKES IT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>


      <!-- Left links -->
    </div>
    <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- Container wrapper -->
</nav>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're expanding the navbar on large break point (`navbar-expand-lg`), to make the content in `navbar-collapse` as two rows, you just need to set its flex direction to column.

There is also an utility class you can use called `flex-lg-column`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#direction

```html
...
<!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-lg-column" id="navbarRightAlignExample">
    ...
</div>
...
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/pLha3x6v/2/